# GET List all indexes on ElasticSearch5

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to list all indexes present on an ElasticSearch5. I tried this:

```
curl -s '<server_adress>/_aliases' -u <user:PAsswd> -k
```

or

```
curl XGET "<server_adress>" -u <user:PAsswd> -k
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `_cat` to list the existing indices,

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/"
```

**Note**

This 403 - Forbidden will happen when the user does not have the appropriate permissions to access.Try assigning the user the the proper role to make sure it has the appropriate permissions.